# Liquid Pre inside Table Cell

Tags: html, css

Basically its a 2 column setup, with a dynamic width content column, and a static width menu column.

The content column is going to contain pre-tags (with code), and I need overflow:auto on the pre-tag inside the table to work.

So far I've had little luck. The nature of the pre tag forces a certain size on the table cell, which in turn refuses to be any smaller than the width of the pre tag.

Can anyone help out?

Ps. I've placed a second pre-tag on the page, which works as intended, but thats probably because it's not inside a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an acceptable solution.
The solution is a negative right margin for the pre (code) element.

Basically, a negative right margin will force the pre to shrink if it needs to.
I made margin-right -800px, and the width 97%.

I noticed that the width, paddings and borders need tweaking if to look good at all resolutions, but the solution works.

A simple solution that was hard to dream up.

[EDIT]

There was a link to an example, but it has been taken down.

Answer (score 1):

Add `white-space: pre-wrap;` to the element. `max-width:100%` may help too.

Comment: Thanks, but I need it to overflow, not wrap. :)